SQLAlchemy+FastAPI: Set up a relationship in model.py to match a return Pydantic Union in schemas
I have been reading post after post on StackOverflow for a solution to this problem but I haven't been able to find one (maybe someone has a link?) as well as reading the SQLAlchemy/FastAPI/Pydantic docs about this.
I am building a website with this stack: SQLAlchemy + FastAPI + VueJS
I have three tables in my model.py: Owner, Dogs, and Cats.
Owner(Base):
__tablename__ = "owner"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    #rest of columns for Owner

    dog_relationship = relationship("Dog", backref="pets")
    cat_relationship = relationship("Cat", backref="pets")



Dog(Base):
__tablename__="dog"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    #same elements as table Cat except it has extra columns

    ownerID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('owner.id'), index=True



Cat(Base):
__tablename__="cat"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    #same elements as table Dog except it doesn't have those extra columns

    ownerID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('owner.id'), index=True

I created a relationship where there are many "cat" and "dog" connected to "owner."
My schema.py is set up like this:
class OwnerBase(BaseModel):
#matches the columns in model.py for Owner

class OwnerReturn(OwnerBase):
id : int

Class Config:
     from_attributes = True

class DogBase(BaseModel):
<matches the columns in model.py for Dog>
pet_type: Literal["Dog"]
ownerID : int

class DogReturn(DogBase):
id: int
Owner : OwnerReturn

  class Config:
     from_attributes = True



class CatBase(BaseModel):
#matches the columns in model.py for Cat
pet_type: Literal["Cat"]
ownerID : int

class CatReturn(CatBase):
id: int
Owner : OwnerReturn

  class Config:
     from_attributes = True

#I read that this would return a union of both lists
CombinedDogCats = Annotated[Union[Dogs, Cats], Field(discriminator="pet_type")]

#This is what I had originally however the JSON doesn't match what I need for a PrimeVue table
class OwnerReturnWithDogsCats(OwnerReturn):
   dog_relationship : list[DogBase]
   cat_relationship : list[CatBase]

#I created this because both dog and cat have the same column names/types except dog has two extra
#ones that are different. So, this has those columns return with nulls for the cat JSON
class CombinedPets(BaseModel):
<has the same elements but
Dog but the extra columns are set to null for cats with this: Optional[int] = None>

And finally my end point:
@router.get('/', response_model=list[CombinedPets]
def get_CombinedPets(request: Request, db:Session = Depends(get_db)):

#queries all results from the Owner table
dogs_cats = db.query(Owner).all()

#sets the data to match the CombinedPets schema
dogs_cats_list: list[CombinedPets] = []

#loops through the list of dictionaries from the query and appends it to the new list: dog_cats_list
for i in dog_cats:
      for j in i.dog:
            dog_cats_list.append(j)
      for j in i.cat:
            dog_cats_list.append(j)

When I call an end point that just queries all the data I get something like this:
[{ owner info},
  "dog" : [ {dog info}],
  "cat" : [{cat info}]
}]

When I call get_CombinedPets:
{"dog" : [{dog info}],
 "cat" : [{cat info}

I would like my JSON to be like this:
{
    owner info,
    combinedPets: [
        {
            dog + cat dictionaries combined where the pet_type differentiates them
        },
        ...
    ]
},

The schema for combinedPets matches what I would like however the Owner table, of course, doesn't recognize it as there is no relationship called "combinedPets"
Is there a way to achieve this through SQLAlchemy + FastAPI or should I create a new dictionary called combinedPets, query the Owner table, and start appending those dictionaries to combinedPets? My only worry is that I don't know how to keep track of which dog and cat dictionary belongs to Owner...
I'm sorry if this is confusing! I am new to this...
Thank you!

Perhaps you could use the Single Table Inheritance method from the SQLAlchemy 2.0 Documentation.
Use something like this:
from sqlalchemy import Mapped, mapped_column, DeclarativeBase


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Pet(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = "pet"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    type: Mapped[str]

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": "type",
        "polymorphic_identity": "pet",
    }


class Dog(Pet):
    # ... dog extra data if exists
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "dog",
    }


class Cat(Pet):
    # ... cat extra data if exists

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "cat",
    }

and then for your endpoint, you wouldn't need to treat dogs and cats separately.
Note: This only makes sense if in your business logic, their classes are alike and the attributes could be inherited.
